# How to delete lines from file without create a temporary file in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need delete line of a file sequentially with ruby, but without success.

If i open the file with w+ flag, it gets completely empty, and if i open with r+ flag, nothing happens.
I even tried do it with by sed's system command, without results too.
What's wrong?

```
$ cat teste.txt 
foo
bar

- This is by ruby way:
$ cat ruby.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby

path = '/home/paulosgf/hack/metasploit/teste.txt'
File.open(path, 'r+') do |file|
    file.each do |line|
        puts(line)
        line.gsub(/^.$\n/, '')
    end
file.close()
end

$ ./ruby.rb 
foo
bar

$ cat teste.txt (nothing happens)
foo
bar

- This is by sed way:
$ cat sed.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby

path = '/home/paulosgf/hack/metasploit/teste.txt'
File.open(path, 'r+') do |file|
    file.each do |line|
        puts(line)
        system("sed -i", "/#{line}/d #{path}")
    end
file.close()
end

$ ./sed.rb 
foo
bar

$ cat teste.txt 
foo
bar
```

I need get the next line, run some processing and delete these line at end, but all lines remains on file yet.

Comment: `file.each do |line|` gives you each line as a string. `line.gsub` returns a new string.

Comment: Your code above is trying to delete **every** line in the file. If that's really the aim, then why not just... delete the file?

Comment: @TomLord I don't want to delete the entire file because i need processone line at a time.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just process one line at a time *and then* delete the file? Unless you need the ability to "pause, and pick up where you left off" (but not have the ability to rerun the whole process), this could be a simpler implementation.

Comment: It's one huge IPs list. I get the next IP and perform a security scanning on it. At end i need remove this IP from list because if script crashes, i can restart it from the next IP and don't repeat the previous.

Comment: @idmean i understanded that this only get the next line from file and format it, without change this file. That's it? In this case i would need open a file stream and operate on his file descriptor directly. How can this be done in ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution on another forum. 
[https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/delete-first-line-of-a-text-file/134316/4]
It only needed to change the focus:

```
[ paulosgf /home/paulosgf/hack/metasploit ] $ cat teste.txt 
john
doe
foo
bar
[ paulosgf /home/paulosgf/hack/metasploit ] $ cat delFirst.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby

path = '/home/paulosgf/hack/metasploit/teste.txt'
remains=''
line=''
each=''

File.foreach(path) { |each|
File.open(path, 'r') {|file| line=file.gets; remains=file.read}
puts("#{line}")
File.open(path, 'w+') {|file| file.write(remains)}
}
[ paulosgf /home/paulosgf/hack/metasploit ] $ ./delFirst.rb 
john
doe
foo
bar
[ paulosgf /home/paulosgf/hack/metasploit ] $ cat teste.txt 
[ paulosgf /home/paulosgf/hack/metasploit ] $
```